# How to prevent a read-only input text field from disappearing when disabled during dark mode?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a read-only text field, but whenever I set it to `readonly`, it greys out on light mode. In Dark Mode, when disabled, its background colour becomes completely black, along with the font colour, making the field and its contents invisible

When I try to style it in CSS using

```css
input:read-only:disabled{
  background: #a0a1a7;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

It is not the same colour as other text fields when disabled, both in Dark mode and in Light Mode.

I have tried adding `value="readonly" readonly` to the `<input>` with minimal success. This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXje2.jpg

I'd rather not set it to `disabled` because I still need to pass the data within the text fields. Any idea what I could do for this?

For what it's worth, I'm using Google Chrome, and the Light/Dark mode settings is set by System Preferences.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` to the background in the style? `background: #a0a1a7 !important;`. It's possible the browser default is causing some unwanted stuff to happen

Comment: Browsers do not change the look of elements based on light/dark mode. What changes your elements' styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect dark or light mode with [`prefer-color-scheme` media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

For example, check [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/kletskovg/pen/gOgzmwY)

Or do something like this

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

  input:read-only {
    background: whie;
  }
}
```